# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 219: but my code is right too

Tags: laravel

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class CreateUserController2 extends Controller
{
    private  $rules =   ['CreateUser'=>'required',];


    public function __construct(){
        //$this->middleware('auth');  //enaable this for auth! //**************todo
    }                

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index(){
        //
        $rows=\App\User::paginate(15);
        return view('auth.list')->with(compact('rows'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create(){         
      //return view('auth.create');


      $userLevelID =\App\Models\UserLevel::orderBy('UserLevel')->lists('UserLevel','UserLevelID');
        return view('auth.register')->with(compact('userLevelID'));

    }    


    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request){

        $rules= $this->rules;         
        $validation = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);  //third param: , $this->messages


    //$val=$validation->passes();
    if ($validation->passes()){

        $data = new CreateUser();
        $data->CreateUser=$request->CreateUser;        
        $data->save();
        return redirect('CreateUser');

    }

    return redirect('CreateUser/create')
        ->withInput()
        ->withErrors($validation)
        ->with('message', 'There were validation errors.');

    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id){
          $rows=\App\User::find($id);

          if (is_null($rows)){
            Session::flash('message','Records could not be found!');
            Session::flash('alert-class','alert-warning');            
            return redirect('CreateUser.index');
          }


          return view('CreateUser.show')->with(compact('rows'));


    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $rows=\App\User::find($id);

          if (is_null($rows))
          {
            Session::flash('message','Data could not be found!');
            Session::flash('alert-class','alert-warning');            
            return redirect('CreateUser.index');
          }

          return view('CreateUser.edit')->with(compact('rows'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

    $validation = Validator::make($request->all(), $this->rules );// 3rd param: , $this->messages
            //dd($request);

    //$val=$validation->passes();
    if ($validation->passes())
    {
        $data=CreateUser::find($id);
        $data->CreateUser=$request->CreateUser;        
        $data->save();
        \Session::flash('message','Data is updated!');
        \Session::flash('alert-class','alert-success');

        return redirect('CreateUser');

    }

    return \Redirect::route('CreateUser.edit', $id)  
        ->withInput()
        ->withErrors($validation)
        ->with('message', 'There were validation errors.');


    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
         Contractor::find($id)->delete();
        return redirect ('CreatUser');
    }
     public function search()
    {
        $searchStr=Input::get('searchString');
        $rows=\App\User::orderBy('AuthID', 'desc')
            ->where('Auth','LIKE', "%$searchStr%")            
            ->paginate(10);
        return view('auth.list')->with(compact('rows'));



    }
}
```

Comment: You have to ask a question.

Comment: You need to post routes.php and the views that is throwing the error. Are you submitting a form?

Comment: yes i am submitting the form from my register but it doesn't accept it, it saves but it doesn't appear

Answer (score 0):

On your routes file, change `Route::get` to `Route::post` (or vice versa).